# Combinding Guice and JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, guice

I have a class that needs to use Dependency Injection (using Guice), but is currently instantiated by JAXB, so obviously nothing is injected. Any idea on how to fix this problem / tell JAXB to use Guice's Injector as object factory?

Thanks for any hint on this!

Answer (score 0):

> tell JAXB to use Guice's Injector as object factory

I don't think it is possible. The closest thing you can get is [on-demand injection](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Injections#On-demand_Injection), that is, injection in already existing object; this will work, obviously, only for injectable fields and methods, not constructors.

By the way, JAXB classes usually represent data, don't they? Then they really *should not have* any dependencies because this is likely a violation of single responsibility principle - data classes should only contain and transfer data, nothing more. Move your logic code out of JAXB classes to separate classes which *operate on* JAXB classes. Then you can use Guice to instantiate these "service" classes.

Comment: That depends on the paradigma: When OO is desired, then the data and the logic are considered to be dependent and hence shall be encapsulated in one ... object. If thinking in Components then data and logic is separated. What the TO wants -- he does not tell us.

Comment: @A.H., no, you're not right. Single responsibility principle which I referred to is 'S' letter in SOLID, which is basic principle of object-oriented design: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design). OOP is absolutely not just a combination of code and data in the same place; see CLOS, for example.